# Reg: Placeholder in the search box

Tags: slickgrid

I have created a slickGrid APP and want to have placeholders in the search box. I can see an example in the Angular version of the slickgrid, yet couldnt see its code. I am however using the Javascript version.[image: My APP]

[image: Angular example online - couldnt find its code though]

Can someone help?

Thank you,
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html as an example.

The filter boxes are created using:

```
grid.onHeaderRowCellRendered.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    $(args.node).empty();
    $("<input type='text'>")
       .data("columnId", args.column.id)
       .val(columnFilters[args.column.id])
       .appendTo(args.node);
});
```

So just add the 'placeholder' attribute to the box, eg:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
```